# Is there an English word for $1/n$?

Tags: terminology

Is there a single English word for $1/n$? Can you say something like "one $n$-tht"?

In Czech, we normally say "jedna $n$-tina".

Comment: "Reciprocal of $n$", "one $n$th", "one on $n$".

Comment: Yeah, you can say "one n$^{\text{th}}$."  I tend to read it, when n is unknown, as "one over n"

Comment: While "one n-th" is technically correct, it sounds wrong. I would say your best bet in this circumstance is to stick with the mathematical notation

Comment: Not a single word, but *"one over $n$"* is the usual pronunciation. Note that *"jedna $n$-tina"* is also not a single word.

Comment: I disagree with @AdamMartens; I find nothing unnatural or "wrong sounding" in the phrase "one $n$-th" (or "one enth," if you prefer).  I use this phrase all the time. ;)